# Dimension of $M_2(\Gamma_0(14))$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

The dimension of $M_2(\Gamma_0(14))$, according to LMFDB, is 4. This should be decomposed into oldforms and newforms, and indeed - the dimensions are 3 and 1, respectively.

According to my understanding, the oldforms should come from spaces with level dividing 14, that is 2 and 7 (and there are none of level 1). However, $\dim(M_2(\Gamma_0(7))=1$ and $\dim(M_2(\Gamma_0(2))=1$, so one oldform (linearly independent to them)  is "missing". Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Do you know how to construct the Eisenstein series $\in M_2(\Gamma_0(2))$ ? And the old subspace from $ M_2(\Gamma_0(d)),d|14$ ? Then look at `M := ModularForms(Gamma0(14),2); M; Basis(M); Basis(EisensteinSubspace(M)); Basis(CuspidalSubspace(M)); Basis(NewSubspace(M)); ` http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Comment: I know how to construct the Eisenstein series, but not the old subspace.

Comment: The old subspace is just saying that for $f,g\in M_k(\Gamma_0(n))$ then $f(z)+a g(dz)\in M_k(\Gamma_0(nd))$ (this is how we can remove one of the Euler factors of a newform, by sending $f$ to $f(z)-a_p(f) f(pz)+p^{2k-1} f(p^2 z)$. The spectral theorem for Hecke operators then gives a decomposition as a linear combination of such modular forms with multiplicative coefficients)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: In my answer I will simplify notation, writing $M_2(N)$ to mean $M_2(\Gamma_0(N))$.

You are correct that $\dim(M_2(7))=\dim(M_2(2))=1$. 
These spaces contain the Eisenstein series of weight 2 as described in section 3.5 of these notes (http://www.few.vu.nl/~sdn249/modularforms16/Notes.pdf). In particular, 
$$E_2^{(7)}(z)=E_2(z)-7E_2(7z)\tag{1}$$
is a modular form in $M_2(7)$ and
$$E_2^{(2)}(z)=E_2(z)-2E_2(2z)\tag{2}$$
is a modular form in $M_2(2)$. These are oldforms as you've stated and together span a 2-dimensional subspace of $M_2(14)^{\text{old}}$. However, the definition of oldforms also encompasses modular forms of the form $f(dz)$ where $f(z)$ is a modular form at a level $M$ strictly dividing $N$ and $d$ divides $N/M$. Hence, the forms $E_2^{(7)}(2z)$ and $E_2^{(2)}(7z)$ are also oldforms. Explicitly we have
$$E_2^{(7)}(2z)=E_2(2z)-7E_2(14z)\tag{3}$$
and
$$E_2^{(2)}(7z)=E_2(7z)-2E_2(14z)\tag{4}.$$
The forms (1), (2), (3) and (4) form a spanning set for $M_2(14)^{\text{old}}$. Although they are linearly dependent, any 3 of them can be used to form a basis for $M_2(14)^{\text{old}}$. This explains why $\dim(M_2(14)^{\text{old}})=3$.

Comment: Thank you, that perfectly explains where I messed up.